# discord.js bot working locally but not on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord.js

I have been attempting to run my discord.js bot on Heroku but I am having trouble getting my bot to join voice channels. Whenever I run my bot locally, everything works well, but when I host it on Heroku, some things don't work.

My bot.js looks like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg');
const opus = require('opusscript');
const token = 'Hidden for obious reasons'
var isReady = true;

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', message => {
     if (message.content === 'ping') {
       message.reply('Test message');
       client.channels.get('Our general chat').send('Test message 2')
      }
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'join') {
      isReady = false;
      const voiceChannel = client.channels.get('ID of our voiceChannel');
      if (!voiceChannel) {
        client.channels.get('ID of our general chat').send('Can\'t get vc');
      }
      else {
        client.channels.get('ID of our general chat').send('Got here 1');
        voiceChannel.join();
        client.channels.get('ID of our general chat').send('Got here 2');
        isReady = true;
      }
    }
});

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === 'leave') {
    isReady = false;
    const voiceChannel = client.channels.get('ID of our voiceChannel');
    voiceChannel.leave();
    isReady = true;
  }
});

client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  if (isReady && newMember.id === 'My friends ID' && oldMember.voiceChannel === undefined && newMember.voiceChannel !== undefined)
  {
  isReady = false;
  var voiceChannel = client.channels.get('ID of our voiceChannel');
  voiceChannel.join().then(connection =>
  {
     // Play the file
     const dispatcher = connection.playFile('./clip.mp3');
     dispatcher.on("end", end => {
       voiceChannel.leave();
       });
   }).catch(err => console.log(err));
   isReady = true;
  }
});

client.login(token);
```

While my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "mybot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Make It Say Dumb Thing",
  "main": "bot.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node bot.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.5.1",
    "ffmpeg": "0.0.4",
    "opusscript": "0.0.7"
  }
}
```

With my Procfile simply being:

```
worker: node bot.js
```

When I run this locally on my machine, everything works perfectly. However, when I host this on Heroku, the .join() function is not working. It prints out 'Got here 1' and 'Got here 2' but the bot never joins the voice chat.

Comment: Since you're saying that the code is running and you're getting messages in the console. Then the only way its not reaching the join function is not entering the condition or the else part of it. 
Try logging the condition and checking it.

Answer (score 1):

you are using 
`client.login(token);`, Not `client.login(process.env.token);`.

The problem is you are not asking the code to look into the Vars.

this is also showing up because you may not be setting the .env right.

In heroku the ENV is under

(Your App) > Settings > Config Vars .

if those are not set up, this is also the problem.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add the ffmpeg build to Heroku

1. Heroku → [Settings] → [Add buildpack]
2. paste the link

   ```
   https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git
   ```
3. [Save changes]

Someone to follow as guidance:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3wsxbMbi5M